# How to determine where, or if, a variable is used in an SSIS package

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

I've inherited a collection of largely undocumented ssis packages.  The entry point package (ie: the one that forks off in a variety of directions to call other packages) defines a number of variables.  I would like to know how these variables are being used, but there doesn't seem to be an equivalent of "right click/Find All References"

Is there a reliable way to determine where these variables are being used?

Answer (score 6):

A hackish way would be to open the dtsx file in a text editor/xml viewer and search for the variable name.

If it's being used in expressions, it should show it and you can trace the xml tree back up until you find the object it's being used on.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the bids helper add-in thats gives you visual feedback on where variables are used in your package. Thats makes it very fast and easy to detect them.Besides that, it offers several other valueable features.

Check out: http://bidshelper.codeplex.com/